# Does UpdateLayout update all child elements as well?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

**tl;dr** When adding children to an element - will the children's layouts be updated when calling `theParent.UpdateLayout();` ?

**Longer version**

I need to call `UpdateLayout` on an element to get some information about its child's properties.

```
theParent.Children.Add(child);
theParent.UpdateLayout();
```

As far as I can see by my testing, it seems like an element's children's children are also updated. i.e. UpdateLayout is recursive. However, checking the documentation [UIElement.UpdateLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.updatelayout)  I don't see that mentioned which I would expect it to. Additionally, because the documentation discourages us from using this method unless absolutely necessary, mentioning some optimizations, I'm worried that testing here is not the way to go - every case might be different. So in conclusion - is it guaranteed that `UpdateLayout` is recursive?

Answer (score 1):

The layout system is inherently recursive. In order for a Button to auto-size itself according to its content, it needs its child elements (i.e. typically a TextBlock label) to be measured first, and *those* child elements may need their children measured too, and so on.

When you create a new UIElement, its layout is initially invalidated (or "dirty"). This means the element is marked as "needs to be laid out during the next layout cycle" -- the layout system will skip elements that are not marked as dirty as an optimization (layout is expensive especially for complex visual trees).

When you add a child element to a panel, the panel invalidates itself because the size or position of the panel may be affected by its children (true for StackPanel and Grid, but not so for Canvas, I imagine).

It's important to understand that layout operations are batched. Since the layout pass is an expensive operation, it is optimal to defer it until a time when no more updates to elements have occurred. Imagine if you added 100 items to a ListView, then instead of performing 100 layout updates each time, it will perform only 1 update at some point after the 100 items were added to the list.

Anyway, back to your question, calling UpdateLayout will *immediately* layout any invalidated elements within the subtree rooted at the element which UpdateLayout was called instead of waiting until the deferred layout pass.

It's interesting that the documentation says

> UpdateLayout is basically equivalent to calling InvalidateMeasure and InvalidateArrange in sequence.

but it appears that it doesn't actually invalidate the layout of the element is was called on, instead it just forces an immediate update of already invalidated elements (but that's just my observation). They're using "basically" very loosely here.